# Issue returning multiple values with a tuple for a function

Tags: c++, return, tuples

Hi I was just having a few issues with a function I made to return multiple values after looking around for ways to return two values from a function, however I still seem to be getting errors from this function. 
I was using this website as a reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple
and am running the default (latest version of c++17).

```cpp
#include <tuple>
std::tuple<int, int> returnCoordinates() 
{
  int xCoordinate = -2;
  int yCoordinate = 2;
  return {xCoordinate, yCoordinate}; //can only do in c++ 17 
}

int main()
{
  int xCoordinate;
  int yCoordinate;
  auto[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] = returnCoordinates(); //only works c++17
  return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is "expression must have a constant value the value of xCoordinate cannot be declared as a constant" and I'm not exactly sure why. **Edit:** As suggested by a commenter I removed the declaration of xCoordinate and yCoordinate, but it now seems to be saying that xCoordinate and yCoordinate are undefined.
However, if I switch out this line of code:

```cpp
auto[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] = returnCoordinates(); //only works c++17
```

with this:

```cpp
std::tie(xCoordinate, yCoordinate) = returnCoordinates();
```

it seems to work, I'm just confused about why this is, apologies for any misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: `auto[xCoordinate, yCoordinate]` declares new variables.  You need to get rid of `int xCoordinate;
  int yCoordinate;`

Comment: @NathanOliver- Reinstate Monica Thanks for that, however, I think I'm now having an issue where it says xCoordinate and yCoordinate are undefined.

Comment: @M.M Sorry for that, that was just a typo on my part, however it still seems to be giving me an error

Comment: The code [is correct](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/yNaGmG) after making those changes, if you are still having trouble then check you posted your exact code and that you are actually using a C++17 compiler

Comment: @M.M Thank you very much! I changed my compiler from default to latest and it all seems to work now! Thank you very much!

Comment: *"`return {xCoordinate, yCoordinate}; //can only do in c++ 17`"*. Doesn't require C++17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters M.M and NathanOliver, I managed to figure out what was wrong.
First of all, I removed my initial declaration of:

```cpp
int xCoordinate;
int yCoordinate;
```

as:

```cpp
 auto[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] = returnCoordinates(); //only works c++17
```

declares new variables.

Also, I wasn't using the latest c++ compiler. To change that go to project-> properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> C++ Language Standard -> Preview - Features from the Latest C++ Working Draft(/std::c++latest)
The default setting for this means that an error will pop up for the following code:
However, otherwise this code now works:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
std::tuple<int, int> returnCoordinates() 
{
  int xCoordinate = -2;
  int yCoordinate = 2;
  return {xCoordinate, yCoordinate}; //can only do in c++ 17 
}

int main()
{
  auto[xCoordinate, yCoordinate] = returnCoordinates(); //only works c++17
  return 0;
}
```